# Angular7 fullcalendar v5 datesSet callback is not triggering

Tags: javascript, angular, fullcalendar

I am using angular full calendar(v5.3) component in my Angular 7 project, I want to trigger an event when the user changes the dates of the view (when navigates between dates)
this is how my calendar options look like, There are no interactions between this calendar and user other than showing data.

```
 @ViewChild('calendar') calendarComponent: FullCalendarComponent;
  calendarOptions: CalendarOptions = {
    headerToolbar: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
    },
    initialView: 'timeGridWeek',
    weekends: true,
    editable: false,
    selectable: false,
    selectMirror: false,
    dayMaxEvents: true,
    nowIndicator: true,
    allDaySlot: false,
    eventSources: [ ],
  };
```

html page

```
<div>
      <full-calendar (datesSet)="handleDates($event)" defaultView="dayGridMonth" [options]="calendarOptions"></full-calendar> 
</div>
```

event hadler function

```
 handleDates(args:any){    
    var startDate = args.view.activeStart;
    var endDate = args.view.activeEnd;
    if(endDate > this.periodEndDate){
      this.periodStartDate = new Date(endDate.getFullYear(),endDate.getMonth()-1, 1);
      this.periodEndDate = new Date(startDate,startDate.getMonth() + 2, 0);
    } else if(startDate < this.periodEndDate){
      this.periodStartDate = new Date(startDate.getFullYear(),endDate.getMonth()-1, 1);
      this.periodEndDate = new Date(endDate,endDate.getMonth() + 2, 0);
    }        
   //this method loads event data from the API;
    this.refreshCalendarData(this.periodStartDate, this.periodEndDate);
  }
```

somehow this handleDates(args:any) is not triggering.

Is there any problem that can be seen in the code?
Basically, I want to load the data for a certain date range and change it when the user changes dates  from UI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found a solution for this, I have used the callback in the wrong way.
`datesSet` should be include in the calendar options and bind in to a method like follows

```
  @ViewChild('calendar') calendarComponent: FullCalendarComponent;
  calendarOptions: CalendarOptions = {
    headerToolbar: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
    },
    initialView: 'timeGridWeek',
    weekends: true,
    editable: true,
    selectable: true,
    selectMirror: false,
    dayMaxEvents: true,
    nowIndicator: true,
    allDaySlot: false,
    datesSet: this.handleDates.bind(this),
    eventSources: [ ],
  };
```

Comment: great I was looking into your issue.. Its better next time if you can post stackblitz sample when you are posting a question of this type.

Comment: Yes I will do like that next time, Thank you very much for your effort